# keep getting internal error with apache perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I have simple sign in page. when i enter abc and 123 as login credentials it should redirect me to login successful page but it keeps giving me the internal error.If login information is not abc and 123 it should redirect to wrong login page. Maybe my if statement is wrong. Can you check my code out? Please.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw( :standard );

$user = param( "user" );
$password = param( "password" );

$user = param( "user" );
$password = param( "password" );

if ($user == "abc") && ($password == "123")
print redirect ( "../../login.htm" );
}

if (!$user ne "abc") || (!$password ne "123")
print redirect ( "../../wrong.htm" );
}
```

Comment: First of all, please add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your program. Then go and fix the errors it will give you. If you want the errors to show up in the browser, [`use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp) but do not leave that in for production.  Also please note that CGI is not in the core Perl distribution with the latest release (5.22) any more.

Comment: When you get an internal error report from a server it should say something along the lines of "More information may be available in your server logs". **Read your server logs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code into a file called test.cgi and then checked it for compilation errors.

```
$ perl -c test.cgi
syntax error at test.cgi line 11, near ") &&"
Unmatched right curly bracket at test.cgi line 13, at end of line
Unmatched right curly bracket at test.cgi line 17, at end of line
test.cgi had compilation errors.
```

So that gives you some places to look. The syntax you're using for your `if` statements is broken in a couple of ways.

Here are a few suggestions that will help you write Perl code more efficiently.

1. Just because CGI programs are written to run on a web server, that doesn't mean they can only run on a web server. Get into the habit of checking for compilation errors outside of the web server environment.
2. When you are testing CGI programs running on a web server, then the errors and warnings will be written to the web server error log. Get into the habit of looking there for more details about problems that you find.
3. Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code and fix the problems that they show you. There is at least one other problem in your code that will be found by `use warnings`.

Finally, writing a CGI program is not the best way to write a web application in 2015. Please look at [some alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).